# -if and -of command line arguments

Tags: c++

I have a simple question, I want to process input from a data file, which is going to be passed like this:

```
./myprogram -if inputfile -of outputfile
```

however I for the life of me have no idea what `-if` or `-of` are, and searching those terms bring nothing.  Are they something I need to account for using `argv` and `argc`?

Comment: They are just text strings.

Comment: Those are just arbitrary strings. Do you know how arguments are passed to your program? Do you know how to use `argc` and `argv`? Also, just about any decent book, tutorial or class should include information on how arguments are passed to a program.

Comment: As you've already got 'if' = 'input file' and 'of' = 'output file'. They're option names specific to your command line.

Comment: There are libraries you can use to simplify this too, e.g. [gflags](https://github.com/gflags/gflags) or [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: Yes I know how to use argc and argv, I just realized its arbitrary strings , so my next step is to use ifstreams and ofstreams to work with inputfile and outputfile. Thanks

Comment: @Rup For applications with complex arguments or requirements then yes those are good libraries. For a beginner just learning about command-line arguments I'd say they are way to complex. For learning, just checking `argc` and `argv` directly is (IMO) much better.